# Python. Многопоточность. Необходимо создать два потока

Tags: python, многопоточность

Необходимо создать две функции потоков, которые выполняют следующие расчеты:

Поток 1: a=(b+3); b = (b-1);
Поток 2: b = (b+2);

Каждая функция потока вычисляет свою формулу в цикле из ста итераций. При вычислении значения переменных а и b выводить на экран.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте этот код:

```
from threading import Thread

a = int(input())
b = int(input())

def flow1(a,b):
    for i in range(100):
        a = (b+3)
        b = (b-1)
        print("Поток 1:", "a -", a, "b -", b)
def flow2(b):
    for i in range(100):
        b = (b+2)
        print("Поток 2:", "b -", b)

thread1 = Thread(target=flow1, args=(a, b,))
thread2 = Thread(target=flow2, args=(b,))

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```